# Fastest moving mean based on time

Tags: python

I currently have a moving average using a list that works but would like to see if thare is a faster way to accomplish this.

```
 strut[i].cpsi = round(bit2UntrimPSI(i) + float(strut[i].trim), 0)
 strut[i].rpsi.append([time.time(), strut[i].cpsi])
 while strut[i].rpsi[0][0] <= time.time() - apsiTimeWindow:
      del strut[i].rpsi[0]
 strut[i].apsi = mean([n[1] for n in strut[i].rpsi])
```

I attempted to accomplish this using Numpy's cumsum function but my only issue with it was the size of the array was constant and to my knowledge could not be controlled by time. Below was that example.

```
def running_mean(x, N):
    cumsum = numpy.cumsum(numpy.insert(x, 0, 0)) 
    return (cumsum[N:] - cumsum[:-N]) / float(N)
```

Answer (score 0):

For a problem like this you want a data structure that can be extended or truncated efficiently on both sides. A Python `list` is efficient at the end, but not at the beginning. A [deque](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/collections.html#collections.deque) is a better  choice. I don't understand your larger problem to clearly enough to frame a demo in terms of your precise code, but here is a demo that illustrates the idea of using a `deque` in a situation where you need to get some more values, throw away values that are too old, and then computes a mean of the surviving values.

```
from collections import deque
from random import randint

# A double-ended queue and the current "time".
pairs = deque()
t = 0

# Check a few rounds.
for _ in range(3):

    # Get some more simulated (TIME, VALUE) pairs.
    n_vals = randint(5, 10)
    for _ in range(n_vals):
        val = randint(1, 10)
        pairs.append((t, val))
        time_incr = randint(1, 20)
        t += time_incr

    # Check.
    print('\nBEFORE :', pairs)

    # Exclude the data older than 30.
    last_time = pairs[-1][0]
    oldest_time = last_time - 30
    while pairs[0][0] < oldest_time:
        pairs.popleft()

    # Get mean of remaining vals.
    vals = [v for _, v in pairs]
    m = sum(vals) / len(vals)

    # Check.
    print('AFTER  :', pairs)
    print('VALS   :', vals)
    print('MEAN   :', m)
```